# Chlorinating specifically one carbon on a symmetrical alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides, alcohols

The final target molecule is 1-chloro-2-amino propane.

The amination step would be simple via reductive amination of 1-chloro-iso-propanone.

Obtaining 1-chloro-iso-propanone would be from nucleophillic addition-elimination of 1-chloro-iso-propanol by H2O under acidic conditions (or oxidation using potassium permanganate but no need for such a reagent when a simpler route available).

However, **assuming you started with only iso-propanol and you wanted to chlorinate only one of the two terminal carbons, how would you do this?** I understand $\ce{SOCl2}$ would of course be the chlorinating reagent, but with no blocking group it would simply attack both carbons. Attempting to add a blocking group would block both carbons also as they are symmetrical and identical.

Comment: SOCl2 would not be the chlorinating agent of choice, all that will do is give you 2-chloropropane from iso-propanol.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. In that case, how could this be done? Free radical substitution? Wouldn't that also cause attack at both terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start from iso-propanol, you can first perform dehydration using concentrated $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ and heat. You will get prop-1-ene.

Then you can use 1 equivalent of $\ce{HOCl}$ (hypochlorous acid) to facilitate chlorohydrin formation. Thus, you will have 1-chloropropan-2-ol. Then, you can simply partially oxidise the secondary alcohol group to a ketone by using pyridinium chlorochromate (PCC) or pyridinium dichromate (PDC), or by performing Swern oxidation, etc. That will be a better way to get 1-chloropropan-2-one (i.e. chloroacetone). After that you can perform reductive amination.

Answer (score 3):

It might be overkill for your purposes, but there is a nice reaction that coverts secondary alcohols to $\alpha$-chloroketones in a one-pot synthesis, using trichloroisocyanuric acid (for instance, they got 75% yield of 2-chlorocyclohexanone from cyclohexanol).  The paper is 'Direct conversion of alcohols to $\alpha$-chloro aldehydes and $\alpha$-chloro ketones' (Jing, Daniliuc, Studer 2014, Org. Lett. 16 (18) pp. 4932-4935).

> Direct conversion of primary and secondary alcohols into the
>   corresponding α-chloro aldehydes and α-chloro ketones using
>   trichloroisocyanuric acid, serving both as stoichiometric oxidant and
>   α-halogenating reagent, is reported. For primary alcohols, TEMPO has
>   to be added as an oxidation catalyst, and for the transformation of
>   secondary alcohols (TEMPO-free protocol), MeOH as an additive is
>   essential to promote chlorination of the intermediary ketones.

[Trichloroisocyanuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichloroisocyanuric_acid) has the advantages that it's inexpensive, widely available and easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can oxidise iso-propanol by any of the methods mentioned above to acetone, directly chlorinate with $\ce{Cl2}$ to chloroacetone then do the reductive amination to 1-chloro-2-aminopropane. It should be noted that this material can form the aziridine fairly easily so should be kept cool. Indeed I would favour doing the reductive amination by forming the benzyl imine then hydrogenating in the presence of $\ce{HCl}$ so that the hydrochloride is formed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use acetone in place of 2-propanol directly.  The selective chlorination on a single carbon can be achieve in one step by using a dichloroemethane solution of sulfuryl chloride ($\ce{SO2Cl2}$) in the presence of methanol (see reference below). Then, using a one of the methods suggested by others here, you may convert resulting 1-chloroprop-2-one (*e.g.*, the reductive amination) to 2-amino-1-chloropropane.

For your convenience, I have put the abstract below:

> Cyclohexanone reacts with sulfuryl chloride in sulfur dioxide, ether, tetrahydrofuran, dioxane, and tetraglyme to give mixtures of mono- and dichlorocyclohexanones. However, when the reaction was carried out in sulfur dioxide solution containing a slight excess of methanol, only monochlorocyclohexanone was obtained in high yield. Almost as good selectivities are obtained in methylene chloride solution in the presence of methanol. A similar **procedure with acetone affords monochloroacetone cleanly**. While phenols do not react with sulfuryl chloride in methylene chloride even under reflux, the chlorination can be induced by the addition of various organic “bases”, resulting in selective monochlorination.

**Reference:**

Sulfuryl chloride as a reagent for selective chlorination of symmetrical ketones and phenols: D. Masilamani, and M. M. Rogic, *J. Org. Chem.*, **1981**, *46(22)*, 4486–4489 (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00335a033).